# Live event on/about Oracle 12c Release 2

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to write a short descriptive email title for an event's invitation.

Do I say

Live event on Oracle 12c Release 2

or

Live event about Oracle 12c Release 2 .

In case it is relevant, Oracle 12c Release 2 refers to a specific version of the Oracle Database.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct. But both of them have omitted words in the interest of brevity.

> A live event on [the topic of] Oracle 12c Release 2
>
> A live event [talking] about Oracle 12c Release 2

I see no reason to consider either of them incorrect.

Comment: Very tangentially related: [this question on why do people use 'on'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/402576/102510).